# elFinder 2.0 Can't select image files whose names include spaces

Tags: elfinder

I have installed elFinder 2.0 rc1 with elRTE in a Codeigniter ver 2.1 environment. elRTE is working and I'm editing and saving files where I choose. However, I have one issue with elFinder when dealing with image files whose names contain spaces. I've checked my `.htaccess`  `RewriteCond` settings and Codeigniter knows not to redirect when dealing with the relevant images files (e.g. with extension `.jpg`), but elFinder throws a 404 error if the image file name contains spaces. I can see a thumbnail of the file in the file manager window, but when I double-click to select (or click the select button), the image does not appear in the preview window and a 404 error appears in the console. As soon as I remove the spaces, it works as normal.

I tried changing the `acceptedName` option in the options I pass to the `elFinder` class which in turn is passed to the `elFinderConnector` class. The default `acceptedName` regex is `'/^\w[\w\s\.\%\-\(\)\[\]]*$/u'`. Regular expressions are my biggest nightmare, so I thought perhaps `\s` was to match spaces, so I stumbled around trying to change acceptedName but it had no effect.

How can I configure elFinder to allow me to select images with names that contain spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaargh! Silly me.  I had forgotten to set `$config['base_url']` in the CodeIgniter config.php file so elFinder was looking in a directory in a completely different application!